# Can IS DISTINCT FROM be combined with ANY or ALL somehow?

Tags: postgresql, null, postgresql-9.3

Is a postgres way of combining `IS DISTINCT FROM` with `ANY` or some other neat way of getting the same result?

```
select count(*)
from (select 'A' foo union all select 'Z' union all select null) z
where foo <> any(array[null, 'A']);

 count
-------
     1
(1 row)

select count(*)
from (select 'A' foo union all select 'Z' union all select null) z
where foo is distinct from any(array[null, 'A']);  

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "any"
LINE 3: where foo is distinct from any(array[null, 'A']);
                                   ^
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/1365):

```
select foo
     , exists (values (null), ('A') except select foo) chk_any
     , not exists (values (null), ('A') intersect select foo) chk_all
from ( values ('A'),('Z'),(null) ) z(foo);

 foo | chk_any | chk_all
-----+---------+---------
 A   | t       | f
 Z   | t       | t
     | t       | f
```

Note that not only the `null` in the "array" but also the `null` in `z` is being compared this way.

Answer (score 21):

Looking at it as a grammar problem, `ANY` is defined as
(in [Row and Array Comparisons](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html)):

> expression operator ANY (array expression)

But `is distinct from` is not an operator, it's a "construct" as we're told in [Comparison Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html):

> When this behavior is not suitable, use the IS [ NOT ] DISTINCT FROM
>   **constructs**

Since PostgreSQL has user-defined operators, we may define an operator/function combo for this purpose:

```
create function is_distinct_from(text, text) returns bool as 
'select $1 is distinct from $2;' language sql;

create operator <!> (
 procedure=is_distinct_from(text,text),
 leftarg=text, rightarg=text
);
```

Then it can precede `ANY`:

```
select count(*)
from (select 'A' foo union all select 'Z' union all select null) z
where foo <!> any(array[null, 'A']);
```

```
 count 
-------
     3
(1 row)
```

Comment: Excellent, insightful answer.

Comment: This is definitely much superior to the workaround I suggested, especially with @Erwin's improvement.

Comment: This answer and @Erwin's suggested tweaks are really excellent. I'm accepting Andriy's but it is just a case of personal preference: I'm sure many will prefer the elegance of yours.

Comment: @JackDouglas: I added an alternative solution with standard operators.

Comment: That's unfortunate...for all intents and purposes, shouldn't `IS DISTINCT FROM` be an operator?  Seems like just a technical limitation of the parser rather than a semantic issue.

Answer (score 17):

#### Operator

This is building on [@Daniel's clever operator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60357/3684).
While being at it, create the function/operator combo using [**polymorphic types**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC). Then it works for *any* type - just like the construct.
And make the function `IMMUTABLE`.
And `PARALLEL SAFE` (Postgres 9.6+).
Using current syntax for `CREATE OPERATOR` (Postgres 12+).

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_distinct_from(anyelement, anyelement)
  RETURNS bool
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE COST 5 AS
'SELECT $1 IS DISTINCT FROM $2';

CREATE OPERATOR &lt;!&gt; (
  FUNCTION = is_distinct_from(anyelement, anyelement)
, LEFTARG  = anyelement
, RIGHTARG = anyelement
);
```

The operator `<!>` does not seem to be in use in any Postgres module.

**If** you are going to use this operator a lot, you might flesh it out some more to assist the query planner. For starters, add the `COMMUTATOR` and `NEGATOR` clauses to assist the query optimizer. Replace `CREATE OPERATOR` from above with this:

```
CREATE OPERATOR <!> (
  FUNCTION = is_distinct_from(anyelement, anyelement)
, LEFTARG  = anyelement
, RIGHTARG = anyelement
, COMMUTATOR = <!>
, NEGATOR = =!=
);
```

And add:

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_not_distinct_from(anyelement, anyelement)
  RETURNS bool
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE COST 5 AS
'SELECT $1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM $2';

CREATE OPERATOR =!= (
  FUNCTION = is_not_distinct_from(anyelement, anyelement)
, LEFTARG  = anyelement
, RIGHTARG = anyelement
, COMMUTATOR = =!=
, NEGATOR = <!>
);
```

But the additional clauses won't help with the case at hand and plain indexes still won't be used. It's more sophisticated to achieve that. (I haven't tried.) Read the chapter ["Operator Optimization Information"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xoper-optimization.html) in the manual for details.

#### Test case

The test case in the question can only succeed if all values in the array are identical. For the array in the question (`'{null,A}'::text[]`) the result is always `true`. Is that intended? I added another test for *"IS DISTINCT FROM ALL"*:

```
SELECT foo
     , foo <!> ANY ('{null,A}'::text[]) AS chk_any
     , foo <!> ALL ('{null,A}'::text[]) AS chk_all
FROM (
   VALUES ('A'),('Z'),(NULL)
   ) z(foo);


 foo | chk_any | chk_all
-----+---------+---------
 A   | t       | f
 Z   | t       | t
     | t       | f
```

### Alternative with standard operators

`foo IS DISTINCT FROM ANY (test_arr)` (illegal syntax) can *almost* be translated to:

```
foo = ALL (test_arr) IS NOT TRUE
```

`foo = ALL (test_arr)` yields ...

... `true`  if all elements are `foo`
... `false` if any `NOT NULL` element is `<> foo`
... `null`  if at least one element `IS NULL` and no element is `<> foo`

So, the remaining corner case is where ...

- `foo IS NULL`
- *and* `test_arr` consists of nothing but `NULL` elements.

If either one can be ruled out, we are done. Therefore, use the simple test if ...

- the column is defined `NOT NULL`.
- *or* you *know* the array is never all NULLs.

Else, test additionally:

```
AND ('A' = ALL(test_arr) IS NOT NULL OR 
     'B' = ALL(test_arr) IS NOT NULL OR
     foo IS NOT NULL)
```

Where `'A'` and `'B'` can be *any* distinct values. Explanation and alternatives, see:

- [Is array all NULLs in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22257626/939860)

Again, if you *know* about any value that cannot exist in `test_arr`, for instance the empty string `''`,  you can still simplify:

```
AND ('' = ALL(test_arr) IS NOT NULL OR foo IS NOT NULL)
```

Result matrix for all combinations:

```
SELECT foo, test_arr
     , foo = ALL(test_arr) IS NOT TRUE  AS test_simple
     , foo = ALL(test_arr) IS NOT TRUE
       AND ('A' = ALL(test_arr) IS NOT NULL OR
            'B' = ALL(test_arr) IS NOT NULL OR 
            foo IS NOT NULL)            AS test_sure 
FROM (
   VALUES ('A'),('Z'),(NULL)
   ) v(foo)
CROSS JOIN (
   VALUES ('{null,A}'::text[]),('{A,A}'),('{null,null}')
   ) t(test_arr)


 foo |  test_arr   | test_simple | test_sure
-----+-------------+-------------+-----------
 A   | {NULL,A}    | t           | t
 A   | {A,A}       | f           | f   -- only TRUE case
 A   | {NULL,NULL} | t           | t
 Z   | {NULL,A}    | t           | t
 Z   | {A,A}       | t           | t
 Z   | {NULL,NULL} | t           | t
     | {NULL,A}    | t           | t
     | {A,A}       | t           | t
     | {NULL,NULL} | t           | f   -- special case
```

This is a bit more verbose than [Andriy's `EXCEPT` solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60348/3684), but it is substantially faster.

Comment: When creating the `OPERATOR`, should the `COMMUTATOR` (and `NEGATOR`, perhaps with the inverse `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` operator) clause be supplied? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xoper-optimization.html

Comment: @losthorse: I added a bit addressing that.

Comment: I am using this operator to eliminate records based on app_status ( integer ) like this `app_status <!> any(array[3,6])`. Unfortunately, it does not have any effect on records. Does it work with integers ?

Comment: @M.Habib: Please ask your question as new *question*. (With all relevant details!) You can always link to this one for context - and drop a comment here to link back.