# Casting an array of texts to an array of UUIDs

Tags: postgresql, join, array, cast, uuid

How can I cast an array of `text`s into an array of `UUID`s?

I need to do a `join` between two tables: `users` and `projects`.

The `users` table has an array field named `project_ids` containing the project IDs as text.

The `projects` table had a UUID field named `id`.

My initial idea was a query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM projects
JOIN users ON
projects.id = ANY(users.project_ids)
```

But that does not work since `users.project_ids` are not `UUID`s so I tried:

```
projects.id = ANY(users.project_ids::uuid[])
```

and even:

```
projects.id = ANY(ARRAY[users.project_ids]::uuid[])
```

but neither one works:

> ```
> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type uuid: ""
> ```

UPDATE

@a_horse_with_no_name is definitely right. The best option should be using an array of UUIDs.

The question now is how can I alter an array of `text` into an array of `uuid`?

The `users` table is currently empty (0 records).

I have tried

```
ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "project_ids" SET DATA TYPE UUID USING "project_ids"::uuid[];
```

which generates

ERROR:  result of USING clause for column "product_ids" cannot be cast automatically to type uuid
HINT:  You might need to add an explicit cast.

> ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "product_ids" SET DATA TYPE UUID
>   USING "product_ids"::UUID;

I have also tried

```
ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "project_ids" SET DATA TYPE UUID[] USING "project_ids"::uuid[];
```

which generates

> ERROR:  default for column "project_ids" cannot be cast automatically
>   to type uuid[]

The column is set to an empty array as default.

I'm running PG version 10.4 and `project_ids` is currently `text[] nullable`.

Comment: You apparently have a empty strings in your array and those can't be converted. You would need to remove those array elements before you can cast the complete array.

Comment: The real question however is: why isn't `project_ids` defined as `uuid[]` to begin with?

Comment: Please remember to start any such question by declaring your Postgres version and the actual table definition - is `project_ids` type `text[]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like has been commented, the column `project_ids` should be `uuid[]`, which would preclude the problem. It would also be more efficient.

To change (with no illegal data in column like you asserted):

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN project_ids DROP DEFAULT;

ALTER TABLE users
ALTER COLUMN project_ids SET DATA TYPE uuid[] USING project_ids::uuid[];
```

You had `uuid` instead of `uuid[]` by mistake.

And this:

> ERROR: default for column "product_ids" cannot be cast automatically to type uuid[]

.. means you have a default value set for the column. That expression cannot be transformed automatically. Remove it before altering the type. You can add a new `DEFAULT` later.

#### Fix to original problem

The efficient fix in your original situation is to remove empty strings from the array with [**`array_remove()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) *before* the cast (requires Postgres 9.3+):

```
SELECT *
FROM   users    u
JOIN   projects p ON p.id = ANY(array_remove(u.project_ids, '')::uuid[]);
```

... *after* investigating why there can be empty stings in that `text[]` column.

Related:

- [Delete array element by index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94639/delete-array-element-by-index/94642#94642)
- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89429/would-index-lookup-be-noticeably-faster-with-char-vs-varchar-when-all-values-are/89433#89433)

#### Fine points

The `[INNER] JOIN` in your query removes users without valid projects in `projects_ids` from the result. Typically, you'd want to *keep* those, too: use `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` instead (with `users` first).

The `JOIN` folds duplicate entries either way, which may or may not be as desired. If you want to represent duplicate entries, unnest before the join instead.

And if your aim is simply to resolve the array of IDs to an array of project names, you'll also want to preserve original order of array elements:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users u
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT project_name  -- use the actual column(s) of your case
      FROM   unnest (array_remove(u.project_ids, '')::uuid[]) WITH ORDINALITY AS p(id, ord)
      JOIN   projects USING (id)
      ORDER  BY ord
      )
   ) p(projects) ON true;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=898d8f84b1d8b0fe860dfe83ccfc6274)* (loosely based on [McNets' fiddle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/222067/3684))

Related:

- [How to preserve the original order of elements in an unnested array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-preserve-the-original-order-of-elements-in-an-unnested-array/27287#27287)

Comment: @Sig: I added the requested `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it but it seems not to work. See my update.

Comment: That's why I strongly suggest to always start questions by disclosing the table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement). You obviously have an undisclosed `DEFAULT` value for the column. Added solution above.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't create the table directly in SQL. That is the reason I missed a few details.  Next time I will try to get the full picture upfront.

Comment: No matter how you created it, you can get the (re-engineered) SQL statement easily with various client tools like pgAdmin3 or pgAdmin4. Or `\dt tbl` in psql, but a `CREATE TABLE` script is best since we can use that to test immediately.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> create table users (user_id int, projects text[]);
>
> insert into users values
> (1, (array['a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11',
>            'b0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-cbb9bd380a11'])::text[]);
>
> insert into users values
> (2, (array['a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11',
>            'b0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-cbb9bd380a11',
>            'a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11'])::text[]);
>
> insert into users values
> (3, (array['f0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11',
>            '',
>            'e0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11'])::text[]);
> ```

> ```
> create table projects (project_id uuid);
>
> insert into projects values
> ('a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11'::uuid),
> ('d0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11'::uuid),
> ('e0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11'::uuid);
> ```

As [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) has pointed out, it fails if some array element has no value. It cannot be converted.

> ```
> select user_id, project_id
> from   projects
> join   users
> on     project_id = any(projects::uuid[])
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type uuid: ""
> ```

However, you could try to cast `project_id` as text in this way:

> ```
> select user_id, project_id
> from   projects
> join   users
> on     project_id::text = any(projects);
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | project_id                          
> ------: | :-----------------------------------
>       1 | a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11
>       2 | a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11
>       3 | e0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=31fd9de379abd23552fefae324b5d7d2)*

Or you could expand the array (unnest) and avoid empty/null values:

> ```
> with usr as
> (
>     select user_id, unnest(projects) as project_id
>     from   users
> )
> select user_id, projects.project_id
> from   projects
> join   usr
> on     coalesce(usr.project_id, '') <> ''
> and    usr.project_id::uuid = projects.project_id;
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | project_id                          
> ------: | :-----------------------------------
>       2 | a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11
>       1 | a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11
>       3 | e0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a6a6535c982663fe5a33281af3950f95)*

Answer (score 0):

> How can I cast an array of texts into an array of UUIDs?

In your case I agree with others that `project_ids` should just be a `uuid[]` to start with. But for the more general problem, you can define a cast to handle this automatically:

`CREATE CAST (text[] AS uuid[]) WITH INOUT AS ASSIGNMENT;`

That will automatically convert things for you when you do an `INSERT` etc. You can also say `AS IMPLICIT` to cover more cases, although that can cause parse-time ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to pass an uuid[]

This did it:

```
 (array['a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11',
           'b0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-cbb9bd380a11',
           'a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11'])::uuid[]
```