# How to pass array of UUIDs *OR* empty array and return implicit (inner join)?

Tags: postgresql, join, array, uuid, empty-string

How would I pass a list that is either full of UUIDs or empty, then return only joined records with those id values or all records if empty?

This question ([Casting an array of texts to an array of UUIDs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222064/casting-an-array-of-texts-to-an-array-of-uuids)) asks for the answer I am looking for, but the selected answer does not answer the question[, it answers the asked text and addresses the errors in the OP's situation].

The closest to correctly fulfilling the need is:

```
FUNCTION getstuff(id_list text[])
  RETURNS TABLE (a_id uuid, b_id, uuid, <other values)
  ... <snip> ... $$
  SELECT a.id, b.id, <etc.>
    FROM schema.a a, schema.b b
    WHERE <other_tests> 
      AND b.id::text = ANY (id_list)
        OR b.id = uuid_or_null(id_list)
  $$;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uuid_or_null(str text)
RETURNS uuid AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN str::uuid[];
EXCEPTION WHEN invalid_text_representation THEN
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

Notes:
Also tried has been `CARDINALITY(id_list)=0`, expecting it to yield TRUE when the id_list array was empty, and thus also return all rows, but it failed due to a syntax error that's since been lost.

*(uuid_or_null modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46433640/2662176))

Comment: `WHERE b.id::text = ANY (id_list) OR cardinality(id_list) = 0` **will** work. https://rextester.com/PJAYVK56198

Comment: I apologize, I thought your code was saved in that rextester and modified it by accident. I may not have explained properly the intent of the code; the id values are used in the join. I created an example here: https://rextester.com/BKIX87785 Note that the function calls expect to return the same as the standard query above them... (I also apologize if the text[] syntax is incorrect.)

Comment: That's because you are using wrong string literals for the UUID. If you write the string literal in lowercase it works: https://rextester.com/CJD78556 or better: pass a proper `uuid[]` parameter to the function: https://rextester.com/TJOBS12038